# How to implement refresh for vue.js app?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I need to add a refresh functionality in my vue.js app that would rerender HTML and also js with data fetch just like `window.location.reload()` but only for the app.

Comment: Why can't you use window.location.reload()?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but as i understood you want to rerender everything.

Vue.js has something that would do what you want:

```
vm.$forceUpdate()
```

But it is not recommended to use it so before use it please [read this](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/356) and also [read this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate)